# OpenGL ES 2.0 texImage2D() giving error 1280

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, textures

I have an Android APP that works on most phones. However on a few phones part way through loading the textures the call to GLUtils.texImage2D() results in error 1280 GL_INVALID_ENUM. There are 8 textures with the following sizes (512x512, 512x512, 512x512, 512x512, 512x512, 512x512, 256x256, 512x1024) all from .png files with an alpha channel. The code loading the textures is shown below. I have managed to catch the exception happening using ARCA "java.lang.RuntimeException: texImage2D 3: glError 1280", so in this instance it was when it was trying to load the 4th texture, when i==3. There is nothing different about the 4th texture compared to the first 3. The only thing that springs to mind is that the memory to load the textures might be too small, but the error number 1280 GL_INVALID_ENUM doesn't seem to fit. Anyone any ideas?

```
private void setupTextures(String[] texFiles) {
    // create new texture ids if object has them
    // number of textures
    mTextureIDs = new int[texFiles.length];

    GLES20.glGenTextures(texFiles.length, mTextureIDs, 0);
    checkGlError( "glGenTextures" );

    for(int i = 0; i < texFiles.length; i++) {
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureIDs[i]);
        checkGlError( "glBindTexture " + String.valueOf(i) );

        // parameters
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
        checkGlError( "GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER " + String.valueOf(i) );

        GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
        checkGlError( "GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER " + String.valueOf(i) );

        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_REPEAT);
        checkGlError( "GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S " + String.valueOf(i) );

        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_REPEAT);
        checkGlError( "GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T " + String.valueOf(i) );

        int ID = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier( texFiles[i], "raw", "com.antonymsoft.slidixcube" );
        InputStream is = mContext.getResources().openRawResource(ID);
        Bitmap bitmap;
        try {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch(IOException e) {
                // Ignore.
            }
        }

        // create it 
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
        checkGlError( "texImage2D " + String.valueOf(i) );

        bitmap.recycle();

    }
}
```

Comment: Check the config of your bitmap (Bitmap.getConfig()), maybe it's an unsupported format.

Comment: I checked running the APP on a device that works, as I don't have access to one that fails. On this device bitmap.getConfig().name() for each bitmap returns the same thing - ARGB_8888. So in this insteance I'm not seeing anything different for the 4th bitmap.  However I have examined the .png files using ImageMagick's identify -verbose and found that the 4th bitmap is stored in a different sub-format. The first 3 show up as sRGB with Alpha and the 4th is Grayscale with Alpha. What do you think? Is it possible that on the phones that fail, the Grayscale + Alpha sub-format is not supported?

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the Android Bitmap class to load textures from PNG files which use the alpha channel.  I have an article that explains the problem here:

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/porting-opengl-games-to-android-on-intel-atom-processors-part-1